# How to loop through directory which have multiple subdirectories?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, directory

I'm have to get the dir path of all sub-directories which has sub-directories under that and print the output to a file which has path for all sub directories. here my question is i can do something like

```
find .mymountpoint/DataRoot/DATAINPUT_*/PER201448_*/IPD_*/ 
 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d
 -printf '/root/mymountpoint/DataRoot/DATAINPUT/PER201448/IPD/%f\n' 
 > dirpathfile.txt
```

But it will print the output of all directory paths to one location which I don't want. I want the sub directory path has to go to that particular dir path only using shell script in linux.

If i'm not clear, apologies and any help will be appreciated.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to print absolute paths. You can use the `realpath` command for that:

```
find ... -exec realpath {} +
```

Comment: Hi @hek2mgl can you please give the exact command, i'm not that familiar with realpath.

Comment: Just your command, but replace `-printf ...` by `-exec realpath {} +`

Comment: Hi @hek2mgl Got this error, [root@testvm01 mymountpoint]#  find ./ShopperVisionDataRoot/DATA_PREP_INPUT/PER_*/IPD_*/* -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec realpath {} + '/%f\n' > /root/mymountpoint/dirpathlist/test.txt
-bash: /bin/find: Argument list too long

Comment: pass only `./ShopperVisionDataRoot/DATA_PREP_INPUT/PER_/` to the find command. Otherwise the argument list gets too long. Then filter using the `-path` argument of `find`. (Check the man page for that)